# Cannot add services to DI in a scaffolder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a customs scaffolder starting from the one in the github repository: I have the scaffolder project that is a modified clone of the mvc scaffolder and a another class library.     Since I want to use **[NotNull]IApplicationEnvironment** inside my library I had to add a reference to **Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration**, **Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration.Common** and **Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces** in my library project.
I would like to add some elements to DI when I run my specific generator and I'm having a few problems.

In the scaffolder module the services are configured in the Program class: I want to add this initialization code inside the generator start up, but I don't find the way.

I tried to add the code in the program class, but I have another problem: the library references the .CodeGeneration module, and to add to the services classes defined in the library I have to add a reference to it in the .CodeGeneration project.json , so I have a circular reference, and this is not supported.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying to define a new service and inject into default services collection so that scaffolder implementations can use that service.

Since the service and the implementation are defined in your class library, for it to be injected you had to modify CodeGeneration class library and add a reference to your class library , and since your class library also implements the custom scaffolder, it needs to reference CodeGeneration class library!

I see 2 choices:

1. You can move the service and implementation definition to CodeGeneration class library (in your fork) and let your class library reference the CodeGeneration but not the other way.
2. Keep your service and implementation in a separate class library, let CodeGeneration reference that, implement your scaffolder in a different class library , and let it reference CodeGeneration.

We may choose to add support to add custom services from other components in the scaffolding framework but that's not done yet. One of the above choices should get you going till then.

Let me know if that helps!